# Why isn't one of my GPU cards showing in sensors?

Tags: graphics, radeon, amd-graphics, temperature, amdgpu

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and have 6 GPU cards connected but only 5 are showing when I call `sensors`. I am using the amdgpu-pro 17.30-458935 drivers with Linux kernel 4.12.0-041200-generic.

All 6 are showing when running the command `lspci|grep VGA` so I know it is there, but when running `sensors`, only 5 are shown.

The output from sensors is below:

```
amdgpu-pci-0500
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:         736 RPM
temp1:        +68.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

amdgpu-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:         560 RPM
temp1:        +56.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +26.0°C  (crit = +127.0°C)
temp2:        +27.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)
temp3:        +29.8°C  (crit = +119.0°C)

amdgpu-pci-0600
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        2210 RPM
temp1:        +74.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

amdgpu-pci-0300
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:         636 RPM
temp1:        +53.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

amdgpu-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
fan1:        1103 RPM
temp1:        +74.0°C  (crit =  +0.0°C, hyst =  +0.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +26.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +25.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +26.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

This setup is being used for a mining rig, and the mining software is only detecting 5 cards as well.

All cards are Radeon RX 570 and 580's and the motherboard is a Biostar TB250-BTC v6.0 with the Intel B250 chipset.

Thanks,

Comment: Which chipset/motherboard are you using?

Comment: It's a Biostar TB250-BTC v6.0 with the Intel B250 chipset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading the kernel to 4.13 fixed this.